# haproxy traffic logs into /var/log/haproxy.log

Tags: haproxy

I am using below haproxy configuration, I see only haproxy service start stop logs in /var/log/haproxy but I do not see logs for calls which makes to haproxy.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    #log         127.0.0.1 local2
    log         /dev/log local0 debug

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000


#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  main *:5000
    acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js
    log /dev/log local0 debug
    option tcplog
    use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             app

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend static
    balance     roundrobin
    server      static 127.0.0.1:4331 check

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
    server  app2 127.0.0.1:5002 check
    server  app3 127.0.0.1:5003 check
    server  app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check
```

Server running RHEL7 and it has selinux enforcing. I have followed all the steps in this link to setup rsyslog for haproxy which selinux enforce. But only logs shows is haproxy service start/stop logs, it doesn't show traffic logs.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-haproxy-logging-with-rsyslog-on-centos-8-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have installed several haproxy services, Centos 6 and 5, I guess.

Config haproxy.cfg contains:

```
global
log         127.0.0.1  local2 info
```

Also, I have created a new file in /etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf (I guess it does the job)

```
# Collect log with UDP
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514

# Creating separate log files based on the severity
local2.* /var/log/haproxy.log
```

After restarting rsyslog daemon, haproxy started writing to log.

P.S. After tests I have added as defaults to stop unnecessary info

```
option                  dontlog-normal
```